# I have an index of users and in my app those users can be friends. How can algolia weight more on friends?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am using firestore and I have a collection of users and each document represents 1 user in the app. I am using algolia to search through my users collection and it’s working perfectly. If I type Miguel all Miguel will show up.

However, I would like for algolia to weight more on friends, so let’s say I have a friend Miguel, if I type miguel I would like to see that Miguel first most of the times? How can I do that?